# How to add the layout.template_node_view into a Toolshelf Panel

Tags: interface

I saw this toolshelf creation, and tried to figured out how he done that without copy all the code?
Without succeed!

[image: TAB Panels from Claas Kuhnen]
Is there an easy way to do this?

layout.template_node_view(ntree, node, input)

layout.template_node_view(???)

Maybe someone could help?

[image: layout.template_node_view]

Comment: That's easy. You can simply re-use the property, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43953/copy-existing-property-from-e-g-properties-window-to-a-custom-panel/43956#43956

Comment: this works for the most simple settings, but for nodes it seem more complicated.

Comment: Voted for reopening :) Can you share what you tried so far? Can't test it at the moment, but re-using the shown code should work as expected. Don't see a difference (any issue) here, since thats how blenders interface is designed.

Comment: lamp = context.object.data     eg: row.prop(lamp, "type", expand=True)<br/> This is how i added the lamp setting  into my toolshelf panel.  <br/>

Comment: Works as explained in the other post. Working example: https://gist.github.com/p2or/a6d9e757123f550255d5

Comment: @poor - what you copied from ui.py doesn't work with lamp objects and the use nodes button doesn't enable in the toolshelf. I think [this example](https://gist.github.com/sambler/572a4979434dc98ab5b2) is as simple as you can make it to handle both lamp and material nodes.

Comment: @sambler You are totally right - thanks for helping out here and providing this *more complete* example. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @poor & sambler! Thank you for the fast help, this is really great! I hoped
to getting along with a few lines less, but after building my panel like in the Working example all works well. I thing this question is answered. Is there something i have to do now? I am new in blender.stackexchange...

Comment: @MKB You're welcome. No I think it's fine. I try to expand the linked answer to cover such cases too ;)