# How to get Property Panel attached My Panel?

Tags: properties, panel

I want to get "**Use Count**" Panel to attach to **My Panel**, what should I do? I know its Class is "**PARTICLE_PT_render_collection_use_count**", as shown below. Hope to get help, Many Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can enable *Developer Extras* right click on the area and select *View Source* to copy the elements to your custom panel. Although that might be a nice exercise for you, I personally don't think having duplicated properties in one UI would make any sense... What's the reason to display the items twice?

Comment: Related or dupe: [Copy existing property from e.g. Properties window to a custom panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43953/copy-existing-property-from-e-g-properties-window-to-a-custom-panel/43956#43956)

Comment: @brockmann I'm writing an addon, related to particles, the image above is just an example. I want to get that table via my addon so that I can quickly access that part without particle switching

Before posting, I tried your way, and your link is copy props, I have done it many times, but this time I want to copy the template_list, it seems much more complicated.

        row.template_list("UI_UL_list", "particle_instance_weights", part, "instance_weights",
                          part, "active_instanceweight_index")

it always gives an error

Comment: What error *exactly*? Please add all relevant information to your actual question. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Consider that you can always change the layout to get "easy access" to the particle properties. I still think your idea can be confusing to users discovering the original uilist at some point. BTW: I don't get any error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qbcd.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reuse the code.**

[image]

Can turn on developer extras and view the source of most of blenders UI.

An option would be to copy the code needed and add to a new Panel class.

A rub is the properties area often has context members unique to the region. For this  case  `context.particle_system` is defined in the properties area in particles tab.

Would instead need to be edited to `context.object.particle_systems.active`

**Monkey patching and passing context object with extra members.**

As an example have given new panel a method which refers to blenders UI class draw method.  A namespace object is used to create a context with the extra members and passed to the draw method as a proxy context object.

Similarly with  the poll method of the `PARTICLE_PT_render_collection` class.

Could do same for  `draw_header`

Have, however,  simply added the use count property to the draw method, it could however be used in a draw header method to replace "Hello World" title.

```
import bpy
from argparse import Namespace

from bl_ui.properties_particle import (
         PARTICLE_PT_render_collection_use_count,
         PARTICLE_PT_render_collection)
         

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        ps = context.object.particle_systems.active
        c = Namespace(**context.copy())
        c.particle_system = ps
        return PARTICLE_PT_render_collection.poll(c) 
    # monkey       
    draw_part = PARTICLE_PT_render_collection_use_count.draw
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        ps = context.object.particle_systems.active
        if ps:
            layout.prop(ps.settings, "use_collection_count")
            c = Namespace(**context.copy())
            c.particle_system = ps
            self.draw_part(c)


def register():
    # fake a pin_id for 3d view.
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.pin_id = None
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.SpaceView3D.pin_id
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*Note, this is only a proof of concept.  Other things to consider when moving from properties area elsewhere is `context.space.pin_id` for when the panel is pinned.  Have added another monkey patch to set pin in 3d view to none.*