# How to add custom options in my addon?

Tags: python

[image]

How do I give the ability in my addon panel to change this options in the particle settings?

Comment: Hi and welcome! What do you want to do *exactly*? Please add more context to your question and add the current state of your code, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Also I'd suggest take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I want to know how i can give my addon panel the ability to control the particle numbers from the addon panel, not from the particle settings panel

Comment: Related or dupe: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43953/copy-existing-property-from-e-g-properties-window-to-a-custom-panel

Comment: didn't know that it even existed, thank you!

Comment: it did so, when i click edit source and choose the file it imported i add those 4 lines of count of particles in my addon. however i still can't change it in my addon, it gives my the operator but it appears as a button and when i click on it nothing happens...